# Send mails using python and outlook

Tags: python, outlook, smtp

I am working on my own software using python. For the bug report part I have created an outlook account. This is becouse if the password leaks it is not a big problem. But I cant find a way to send mails using outlook.
This is what i've tried

```
from smtplib import SMTP
server = SMTP("smtp.outlook.com", 465)
server.starttls() 
server.login("myoutlookaccount@outlook.com", "mypassword")
```

and this is the error I got after 5 minutes of waiting.

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Een verbindingspoging is mislukt omdat de verbonden party niet correct 
heeft geantwoord na een bepaalde tijd, of de gemaakte verbinding is mislukt omdat de verbonden host 
niet heeft geantwoord
```

(translation)

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party was not correct 
replied after a certain time, or the connection created failed because the connected host 
did not reply
```

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks for the translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some values in there are not correct for outlook.com. Here's how it should look:

`server = SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587)`